# Calling js functions with callbacks using purescript's FFI

Tags: ffi, purescript

I'm trying to call the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` javascript function from purescript, but I've come across two problems.

In javascript it would be called using something like

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) { ... });
```

where position is an object.

Firstly, I don't know what the return type should be as it doesn't return anything, but instead calls a callback.

Secondly, I don't know what type to use for the callback, as the function can't be pure as it's result won't be returned.

So far I have

```
foreign import geolookup "function (callback) {\
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(callback);
    \}" :: forall eff a. Eff (geolookup :: GeoLookup | eff) {}

geolookup \position -> ...
```

So here my type signature for the foreign function is `forall eff a. Eff (geolookup :: GeoLookup | eff) {}`, however I know there should be a callback paramter in there too before the Eff. I'm just not sure how to write the type signature or implement it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Firstly, I don't know what the return type should be as it doesn't return anything, but instead calls a callback.

You've correctly identified the return type as `Unit`, or `{}`, but the `geolookup` function itself is effectful, so should be wrapped with the `Eff` type constructor.

> Secondly, I don't know what type to use for the callback, as the function can't be pure as it's result won't be returned.

So let's give the callback an appropriate type. As an effectful function, something like `a -> Eff _ b` makes sense, and to avoid duplicate labels in  rows, we're forced to include the `GeoLookup` effect in our row. So let's give the callback the type `Position -> Eff (geolookup :: GeoLookup | eff) Unit`.

Then the full type of our function becomes

```
foreign import data Position :: *

geolookup :: forall eff. (Position -> Eff (geolookup :: GeoLookup | eff) Unit) ->
                         Eff (geolookup :: GeoLookup | eff) Unit
```

In the FFI, we can wrap the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` call to be compatible with this type. Using the FFI style from the 0.7 compiler:

```
exports.geolookup = function(callback) {
  return function() { // Outer Eff
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(p) {
      callback(p)(); // Extra () due to inner Eff
    });
  };
};
```

At this point, you might like to look into types like `ContT` or `Aff` to wrap up your function in a more composable way.

You might like to read the article on [how to use the Eff monad](https://github.com/purescript/documentation/blob/master/guides/Eff.md).